# Can't convert autofiltered range values to array - only does the first one

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, autofilter

Only the first value of the returned list of filtered cells is returned.  Works otherwise if I'm not using filtered cells:

```
Dim tmp, tmpfilter As Variant

' returns the list of cell values
tmp = teamRosterSheet.Range("D2", teamRosterSheet.Range("D2").End(xlDown)).Value

' returns 3
Debug.Print teamRosterSheet.Range("D2", teamRosterSheet.Range("D2").End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count    

' but only returns the first cell value and not all three other cells in my example (filtering is working ok as I can see the 3 non-contiguous rows only been shown)
tmpfilter = teamRosterSheet.Range("D2", teamRosterSheet.Range("D2").End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very good question!  When you grab an AutoFiltered column into a **VBA** array, you must loop over SpecialCells.  For example:

.

[image: demo]

.

```
Sub GrabData()
    Dim rGrab As Range, ary()
    Set rGrab = Range("B2:B13").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    ReDim ary(1 To rGrab.Count)
    i = 1
    For Each r In rGrab
        ary(i) = r.Value
        i = i+1
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: i was hoping to get away from a loop to populate the array but alas i shall endure. thanks.